# Microsoft sql server ssis automatic process cube creation

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssas, cube

I deployed a Microsoft sql server 2008R2 with sample data.

Installed report builder 3.0, visual studio 2008.

These all installed on a windows server 2008 enterprise.

I successfully created Cube from ssas and used it for deploying report.

Now, my next task is make this process automatically.

I am thinking is that possible to tell the ssis to do the following

1. Creating a new cube base on the latest sql data and use current date for its name. This will do it daily.

Or

2. Copy the current cube and rename it. Use the same cube building information for a new cube.

Note that I also thinking is that possible to use linux bash script to rename the cube before ssis scheduled task kick-in.  so this way can skip one step on above method.

The reason behind that is because of the high up want to have the cube created daily and so they can check them and keep a record for those data.

Any suggestion are welcome as I am a newbie on ssas cube thing and so my thought may not be on tge right track.

Comment: Dont know why people downvote it. I didnt ask for code or step by stey instructions.  Just asking are these possible to process and am I on the right track.

Answer (score -1):

I think it can be done. But it is hard to meet your requirement with existing build-in component in SSIS, an alternative is to use script task to build .net code and create the XMLA and tsql script to process the logic you needs. Consider you're new to all that thing, I will not recommend you to do that. But it do works.
Hope it can help you!

Comment: Ive got the batch xmlns while the processing the cube and I got the dbo thing after the Run process is done. Is that possible to use them for ssis to create new cube?

Comment: I haven't got a chance to look into it. In my view, if it is supported of creating cubes by XMLA, it works by writing implementing the logic in SSIS. You can think of XMLA as TSQL, you can write the tsql to create database right? Why not cube by XMLA?